# por que aparece extraño espacio en blanco al momento de redimencionar mi pagina web?eb

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Hola he estado haciendo una pequeña aplicación, todo bien pero me he dado cuenta que al momento de redimensionarla aparece un extraño espacio en blanco al llegar a ciertos pixeles(340 mas o menos) he probado varias cosas que encontré en otra publicación que vi similar([No puedo quitar el espacio en blanco de mi página web por ningún método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436048/no-puedo-quitar-el-espacio-en-blanco-de-mi-p%c3%a1gina-web-por-ning%c3%ban-m%c3%a9todo)) pero nada me ha funcionado de momento, esto es lo que sucede en cuestión:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí mi código css:**

```
 body {
  margin: 0;
}

.Formulario {

  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cuadro_tramites {
  width: 100%;
  height: 515px;
  background-color: #6346BA;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.cuadro-scroll {
  max-height: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.cuadro-permiso-circulacion {
  height: 290px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.boton_rojo {
  width: 240px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #DB3069;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.label1 {
  color: black;
}

.btnEventos {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6346BA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -55px;
}

.btnSolicitarInfo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6346BA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 35px;
}

.btnAudiencia {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6346BA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 130px;
}

.btnConocelosP {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #6346BA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 230px;
}

.botones_circulos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
}

.contenedor_parrafos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 575px;
}

.cuadro_directo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}

.p_envivo {
  float: right;
}

.cuadrado1 {
  background: #034D8E;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 15px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.cuadrado2 {
  background: #2885AD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: aliceblue;
  width: 95%;
  height: 15px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.label2 {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.bienvenidx {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tramitx {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.botones_fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  top: 70%;
  left: 5%;
}

.cuadro_logo {
  background-color: #6346BA;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo_muni {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.boton {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #6346BA;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.i_Eventos {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.i_solicitar_info {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.i_solicitar_audiencia {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

.i_conoce_losP {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.contenedor_tramites {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.botones_espacio {
  width: 350px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.i_cuadro_tramites {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.G_en_vivo {
  position: absolute;
}

.alineador_b {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.alineador_p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

**y aqui mi codigo Html**

```
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="Formulario" id="Formulario">
  <div class="cuadro_tramites">
    <div class="cuadro_logo" id="cuadro_logo">
      <img class="logo_muni" src="imagenes/logomuni.png" width="100" height="80">
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor_tramites">
      <h3 class="bienvenidx">Bienvenid@</h3>
      <h4 class="tramitx">Selecciona el trámite que deseas:</h4>
      <div class="cuadro-scroll">
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Permiso de circulacion</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_cuadro_tramites" src="imagenes/coche.png" width="170px" height="170px">
          <a class="boton_rojo" href="https://home.municipalidadgorbea.cl/archivos/3118">Pagar aqui</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Pago derechos de aseo</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_cuadro_tramites" src="imagenes/pago aseo.png" width="170px" height="170px">
          <a class="boton_rojo"
            href="https://www.sem.gob.cl/pago/buscar.php?pago_id=4&inst_id=69191200&setiframe=0">Pagar aqui</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Tramites departamentos de obras</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_cuadro_tramites" src="imagenes/en-construccion.png" width="170px" height="170px">
          <a class="boton_rojo" href="https://mattgr05.github.io/Proyecto-app-muni/index4.html">Revisar aqui</a>
        </div>
        <div class="cuadro-permiso-circulacion">
          <label class="label1" for="Permiso-circulacion">Registro social de hogares</label>
          <hr>
          <img class="i_cuadro_tramites" src="imagenes/registro social.png" width="170px" height="170px">
          <a class="boton_rojo" href="https://rsh.ministeriodesarrollosocial.gob.cl/portada">Revisar aqui</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="botones_circulos">
    <div class="alineador_b">
      <a class="boton" href="https://mattgr05.github.io/Proyecto-app-muni/index5.html"><img class="i_Eventos"
          src="imagenes/ico eventos.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_b">
      <a class="boton"
        href="https://www.portaltransparencia.cl/PortalPdT/web/guest/directorio-de-organismos-regulados?p_p_id=pdtorganismos_WAR_pdtorganismosportlet&orgcode=e1c4b38162d39"><img
          class="i_solicitar_info" src="imagenes/ico solicitar info.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_b">
      <a class="boton" href="https://www.leylobby.gob.cl/instituciones/MU099"><img class="i_solicitar_audiencia"
          src="imagenes/ico solicitar audiencia.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_b">
      <a class="boton" href="https://mattgr05.github.io/Proyecto-app-muni/index3.html"><img class="i_conoce_losP"
          src="imagenes/ico conoce los programas.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor_parrafos">
    <div class="alineador_p">
      <p>
      <h5>Eventos<h5>
          </p>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_p">
      <p>
      <h5>Solicitar informacion<h5>
          </p>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_p">
      <p>
      <h5>Solicitar audiencia<h5>
          </p>
    </div>
    <div class="alineador_p">
      <p>
      <h5>Conoce los programas<h5>
          </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cuadro_directo">
  <h3 class="G_en_vivo">Gorbea en vivo:</h3>
  <h4>
    <p class="p_envivo">En vivo ahora </p>
  </h4>
  <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ceqgwo7U28Y" title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="botones_espacio">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <hr width="90%">
    <a class="cuadrado1" href="tel:452972000">Llámanos</a>
    <a class="cuadrado2" href="https://mattgr05.github.io/Proyecto-app-muni/index2.html">Envíanos un mensaje</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elimina los overflow,   pon overflow: hide;

EJEMPLO: https://jsfiddle.net/enlinea777/12xzkdt0/1/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola, gracias por el cometario, pero el recuadro morado contiene 3 cuadros blancos mas hacia la derecha es por eso que tengo un overflow x en un div que contiene todo el recuadro morado y en general se me desordenado todo el código jaja, pero gracias de igual manera.